# 240 to thermostat for electric heat reading 120v and 70v

Tags: electrical, wiring, 120-240v

I had an electrician in to replace some thermostats a few months ago. One of the thermostats that was replaced was an older analog dial type. The electrician replaced it with a digital thermostat seemed to be working briefly when installed, then stopped working. I tried to contact the electrician, but never heard back from him.

Recently National Grid came out to replace some aged thermostats in my multifamily home. When the electrician got to this bedroom, he installed the thermostat, and it would click on, then turn off, and would just do this over and over. So he checked the voltage, one line is 120v and the other is 70v. He told me he he tested at the breaker where the power comes out and both lines are 120v. He could not put a finger on what it would be doing that, and really, he wasn't there to troubleshoot electrical problems, so I was grateful that he did as much checking as he did.

So, I'm hoping someone here would be able to give me some insight as to what could be happening?

Comment: "National Grid" indicates you're in the UK, correct? How about providing the brand/model of the new thermostats and a picture of how they're wired (shut off the breakers before pulling the wiring - you're working with 240v and we don't want you dead). Brand/model of the HVAC equipment would probably be helpful, too.

Comment: @FreeMan  National grid is a name of an energy company in NY, RI and Mass(google search).  UK usually does not use 120v, except for some construction sites(I think).  They do not use a pair of 120 for 240.

Comment: Ah, fair enough, @crip659. The rest of the request still stands, though - pictures and brand/model numbers of the equipment involved helps troubleshooting.

Comment: @FreeMan: I'll get some photos as soon as I can. In regards to brand/model of HVAC, it's eclectic baseboard heat, these were installed when I bought the home, so I'm not certain the make/model, but I can look for a label.

Please correct me if I'm wrong, but if the cables that are coming from the electric panel are both 120v measured after the breaker, but when the measured at the wall where they come out at the thermostat are measuring 120v and 70v, wouldn't that indicate there is a problem with the wiring somewhere between the breaker and where wires come out at the thermostat location?

Comment: Wait, so in NY/MA you can just open a company and call it "National Grid"?  Maybe I'll open a security consultancy and call it Special Branch, or a satellite mapping service and call it GCHQ.

Answer (score 2):

Somewhere in that line, between the breaker where it's 120 to neutral (or ground) and the thermostat where it's not, there is a bad connection. High resistance is bleeding off roughly 50 volts under whatever conditions it was measured. That value will generally change (likely quite drastically) with the amount of current being drawn on the circuit.

Such a connection is going to be heating up and could cause a fire. So, you need to track it down and fix it. If it's not at either end, it's at some junction box in the middle of the run (possibly a junction box on the baseboard heater, possibly just one under a blank plate somewhere else, depending how the wires are routed.)

Comment: thank you. I'll have to look where the cable is coming into the heater itself. If the wire going to the heating unit is nicked and touching the heater, would that trip the breaker, or could it be causing this issue I'm having? The house was re-wired in 2009, and as far as I'm aware, this is a new issue. Could it possibly be a rodent issue?

Comment: With "just the right amount of contact" it could be a short to ground that's not a "dead" short (i.e. you could conceivably have a high-resistance short to ground that does not run enough current to trip the breaker) but that's **far less common** than a short that will trip, or a poor connection that is not shorting to ground. An expensive "debug & safety" test would be to get a suitable double-pole AFCI/GFCI breaker to try on the circuit and see if, and for what reason (they give codes, usually) it trips. That's assuming you are comfortable working in the panel to change a breaker.

Comment: ...If not, you hire an electrician to sort the problem, rather than hiring one to try swapping in an AFCI/GFCI breaker as you try to sort the problem yourself.